# How do I draw multiple glQuads contained in a list?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I made a little lwjgl progrm in which I can create boxes by pressing a button. However, I don't seem to be able to draw multiple quads within a for loop.

Here's my code: I have a box class so that I can deal with many boxes

```
package LWJGL_Learn;

import java.util.Random;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.*;

public class Box {

    static int xPos, yPos, boxWide, boxHigh;
    public Box(int width, int height) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        xPos = ran.nextInt(width);
        yPos = ran.nextInt(height);
        boxWide = ran.nextInt(40)+20;
        boxHigh = ran.nextInt(40)+20;
    }
    public void draw() {
            glVertex2f(xPos, yPos);
            glVertex2f(xPos + boxWide, yPos);
            glVertex2f(xPos + boxWide, yPos + boxHigh);
            glVertex2f(xPos, yPos + boxHigh);   
    }
}
```

I then, in my main file, have a LinkedList which stores my box classes, initialized as such

```
static LinkedList<Box> boxes = new LinkedList<Box>();
```

The code which actually renders it is below:

```
glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
for (int x = 0; x < boxes.size(); x++) {
    boxes.get(x).draw();
}
glEnd();
```

The problem with this code is that it only seems to draw the box most recently added to the list. I'm not exactly sure why this is, but when I added code in to print the box list at the end of execution a correct sized list came up every time. I assume this means that every box is iterated over in the for loop, which means that somewhere in the code the previous box is being cleared from the screen before the next on gets drawn.

I think. Can you guys correct my code and explain to me why openGL does this?

If required, I can post the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not GL which is only rendering one quad, it is your code only defining one quad, and then rendering 'n' copies of it.

This:

```
static int xPos, yPos, boxWide, boxHigh;
```

declares your box parameters as being static - which means they are shared by all instances of a box.

Comment: oh. I was under the impressions static fields were only shared by members of... never mind. Thanks, and you managed to clear one of my huge misconceptions about java!